# Patch does not create new files

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, patches, supee-6788, mage-shell

If I run the `./PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-10-27-12-00-16.sh` no new files are created. For example `app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php` in the patch but does not exist after the patch. No error about this is shown.

I do have rw access and can create the file:

```
touch app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
```

Any idea why the file is not created?

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -la app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/
total 124
drwxrwxrwx+ 8 myuser apacheuser  4096 Feb  1 12:41 .

-bash-4.1$ touch app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
-bash-4.1$ ls -la app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
-rw-rw-rw-+ 1 myuser apacheuser  0 Feb  1 12:41 app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php

-bash-4.1$ ./PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-10-27-12-00-16.sh
...
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
...
```

If I create one of the missing files the patch skips this file, so it is doing something:

```
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, if it fails to patch one file, no file gets patched at all. Even if it tells you "patching file".

Fixing the other minor problems solved it.

PS: You might need to check line-endings CRLF vs LF!

Comment: @simonthesorcerer thanks. I will as soon as I can ;) `You can accept your own answer tomorrow`